# Update a Gridview from a JQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use a JQuery UI Slider to update a gridview in Visual Studio. Can someone tell me how to use postback or some other function to achieve this. Thanks for your time.

JQuery UI Slider

```
  <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#sliderrange1").slider({
                        range: true,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 2500,
                        step: 100,
                        values: [0, 2500],
                        slide: function (event, ui) {
                            $("#amount").val("MW " + ui.values[0] + " - MW " + ui.values[1]);
                            $("#minval").val(ui.values[0]);
                            $("#maxval").val(ui.values[1]);
                        },
                        stop: function (event, ui) {
                        }
                    });
                    $("#amount").val("MW " + $("#sliderrange1").slider("values", 0) +
                    " - MW " + $("#sliderrange1").slider("values", 1));
                    $("#minval").val($("#sliderrange1").slider("values", 0));
                    $("#maxval").val($("#sliderrange1").slider("values", 1));

                });
            </script>
```

I can display them on the site, but what I need to do now is to preserve the values selected from the Slider to update a Gridview that uses SQL Commands to query a database.

HTML

```
<p>
                <label for="amount">
                    <br />
                    Output range:</label>
                <input type="number" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />

                <label for="minval">
                    <br />
                    minval:</label>
                <input type="number" id="minval" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />

                <label for="maxval" visible="false">
                    <br />
                    maxval:</label>
                <input type="number" id="maxval" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
            </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't postback.  Do it using AJAX instead.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/